# Remove category and subcategory from the product url opencart

Tags: php, seo, opencart, opencart2.x

I want to remove category and sub-category name from the product URL in the opencart. I have made changes in seo_url.php file. Where I have replaced

```
$url .= '/' . $query->row['keyword'];
```

with

```
$url = '/' . $query->row['keyword'];
```

But still the url is not changed. Can any one suggest me what to do. I am using opencart version 2.0.3.1

Comment: enable seo url?

Answer (score 2):

are you sure you've replaced all?

```
$url .= '/' . $query->row['keyword'];
```

in seo_url.php file there is 3 matches.

Answer (score 0):

Replace all occurrence of

```
$url .= '/' . $query->row['keyword'];
```

with

```
$url = '/' . $query->row['keyword'];
```

to remove category from product url.
there are only two occurence of it